# Issue with Duplicate IP CIDRs in an AWS S3 bucket policy whitelist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an **AWS S3 bucket policy whitelist** that contains duplicate entries (2 of each) for the same IP CIDR range. Does anyone know if this will cause issues (i.e. not being able to download large data sets). Currently I have issues with a few of them, but not 100% sure if its a client issue or something to do with the whitelisting. Cheers!

We will remove these in our next sprint, but this will not be for 1 week.

Comment: Are you saying that a Bucket Policy has an **Allow** policy with IP address **condition statements** and those conditions contain duplicates? If so, it should be no problem. What do you mean by "I have issues with a few of them"?

Comment: Hi John,Yes indeed, the allow policy has duplicate IP CIDRs, I didn't think it should be an issue but couldn't find an answer anywhere. I am having an issue where they cannot retrieve Large data sets, which happens when an IP is not in the allow list BUT it could also be an issue in the client side of course.

Comment: What do you mean by "where they cannot retrieve Large data sets"? Is there an error message?